Convert Pandas sales data to pie chart report
I have the following sample sales data
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

data = {'Day': ['Monday', 'Monday', 'Monday', 'Monday', 'Tuesday', 'Tuesday', 'Tuesday', 'Tuesday', 'Tuesday', 'Tuesday', 'Wednesday', 'Wednesday', 'Wednesday', 'Wednesday', 'Wednesday',
    'Wednesday', 'Wednesday', 'Wednesday', 'Thursday', 'Thursday', 'Thursday', 'Thursday', 'Thursday', 'Friday', 'Friday', 'Friday', 'Friday'],
    'Employee': ['Jack','Jill','Fred','Ginger','Jack','Jill','Jill','Fred','Ginger','Ginger','Jack','Jack','Jill','Jill','Jill','Fred','Fred','Ginger','Jack','Jill','Fred','Ginger','Jack','Jill','Fred','Fred','Ginger'],
    'Fruit': ['Apples','Oranges ','Pears','Apples','Oranges ','Pears','Apples','Oranges ','Pears','Apples','Oranges ','Pears','Apples','Oranges ','Pears','Apples','Oranges ','Pears','Apples','Oranges ','Pears','Apples','Oranges ','Pears','Apples','Oranges ','Pears'],
    'Qty': ['2','4','3','5','1','2','4','2','3','5','3','1','2','4','1','5','2','1','4','3','1','5','4','1','2','4','2']
    }

df = pd.DataFrame(data)

I extract the total sales of each type of fruit for each employee:
df.groupby(['Employee','Fruit'])['Qty'].sum()


I now want to present this in a pie chart for each employee grouped as a 2x2 plot. In some sense I think the fruit descriptors should become column indexing, but it might not be necessary.
What is the best method to achieve this?

Code
The simplest code solution is to use plot with subplots parameter.
df['Qty'] = df['Qty'].astype(int) # Your Qty column is str.
out = df.groupby(['Employee', 'Fruit'])['Qty'].sum().unstack(level=0)
out.plot(kind='pie', subplots=True, layout=(2, 2), legend=False)


